# Upload and rename two different files in two different folders using django?

Tags: python, django

I could upload two different files in the same folder using django. But I have to upload it to two different folders and also rename the files I uploaded as target.{file_extension} and probe.{file_extension}.I have no idea as I am a beginner to django.Could anyone please help me with my issue. 
My codes are:

In django model.py

```
dirname = datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S')

class Document(models.Model):
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=dirname)
```

In views.py

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()                      

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # An empty, unbound form

    documents = Document.objects.all()

    return render(
        request,
        'personal/basic.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form}
    )
```

And in my basic.html

```
<form action="/simulation/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" single>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name = "file1"/></p>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check django docs for [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) you see upload_to supports custom method:

(from django docs)

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

as you can see in your custom method you have access to current instance which can be used for generating your custom path to save file.